# Getting "express.default is not a function" error when i run node server in a container

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm getting an express.default is not a function error when i run my node server inside a remote container.

Any clues?

main.ts file:

```
import * as express from 'express';
...
const server = (express as any).default();
...
```

logs:

```
2020-09-04 10:58:29/main.js:112
/main.js:112
2020-09-04 10:58:29const server = express.default();
const server = express.default();
2020-09-04 10:58:29^
^
2020-09-04 10:58:29TypeError: express.default is not a function
TypeError: express.default is not a function
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Object.<anonymous> (/main.js:112:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (/main.js:112:35)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Object.execCb (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1946:33)
at Object.execCb (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1946:33)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Module.check (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1133:51)
at Module.check (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1133:51)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Module.enable (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
at Module.enable (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Object.enable (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1807:39)
at Object.enable (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1807:39)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Module.<anonymous> (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1411:33)
at Module.<anonymous> (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1411:33)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at /node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
at /node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
2020-09-04 10:58:29at each (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
at each (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Module.enable (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1363:17)
at Module.enable (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1363:17)
2020-09-04 10:58:29at Module.init (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
at Module.init (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
```

Comment: Do you have same node version locally and inside container?

Comment: Nvm it's failing in both places

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig?

Comment: `import express = require('express');` or `import express from 'express';` with `--esModuleInterop`. Type assertions against an import (like your `import * as express from 'express'; const server = (express as any).default()`) mean you are in the weeds.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you didn't change anything in `tsconfig.json` which means you leave this option `esModuleInterop: false`, so you just simply import as namespace, without calling any `default` function:

```js
import * as express from "express";

const app =  express();

// compiled code will require as normally

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

Or if you switch to be true `esModuleInterop: true`, you would import without namespace like this:

```
import express from "express";

const app =  express();


// compiled code will call default function by checking first

var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
const express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
const app = express_1.default();
```

Comment: I'm getting [TypeError: (0 , express_1.default) is not a function for my code. 

import express from "express";
const app = express(); // error

Is the interop option fix this or not fix this?

Comment: I added `esModuleInterop: true` and the error went away

Comment: is there any downside to esModuleInterop?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts To my best of my memory I couldn't find one :)

Answer (score 4):

Turn on   "esModuleInterop": true, from your tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error too, but it was because my file name was `express.js`, changed the filename to `server.js` and it started working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).