# Invocation of Typescript AWS Lambda in VS Code debug builds using arbitrary tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, tsconfig

I'm trying to run code for a Lambda function written in Typescript via SAM under the VS Code debugger, which has AWS Toolkit installed. The code does build and deploy successfully to the cloud, but running it under the debugger fails with error described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744824/getting-express-default-is-not-a-function-error-when-i-run-node-server-in-a-co).

My build specifies `esModuleInterop: true` in `tsconfig.json`, and the SAM build ignores it, building instead as if `esModuleInterop: false`. It appears to use an arbitrary `tsconfig.json` given below, instead of the one in the project directory. How can I get it to use my `tsconfig.json`, or at least pass specific compiler options to *tsc*?

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
        "node"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "inlineSourceMap": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share your launch config? Does it work if you use a `invokeTarget.target:template` launch config (which expects a SAM `template.yaml` file in your lambda project)?

> It appears to use an arbitrary tsconfig.json given below, instead of the one in the project directory

That's currently a limitation of AWS Toolkit for VSCode when you invoke a typescript lambda with `invokeTarget.target:code` (a [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode) would be appreciated!):

https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/blob/acbd172d8e0de799e880ba83aff1f6a5562f11af/src/shared/sam/debugger/typescriptSamDebug.ts#L137-L138

Comment: Thanks! So the behaviour I see is documented as a known limitation. So far I haven't been making my own template.yaml files. More practically I can see how I can eliminate my dependence on _esModuleInterop_.